# Random Cascading Combo boxes

Tags: c#, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I have two combo boxes. The user must be able to select one of them randomly, and once he selects one of them, the other filter must be filtered accordingly. Is this doable in C# or ASPX?

Comment: Cannot help you without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

This demo should give you a good start:

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx